# vscode clang++: no such file or directory: 'main.cpp'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

Okay, so this is terribly frustrating.

I am simply trying to using clang++ in my VSCode editor to compile a very simple main.cpp program, located in the 'main' module of my project.

The project hierarchy is as follows:
${workspaceFolder}/
  cpp/
    main/
      main.cpp

There are many other folders and files that I have purposefully omitted for the sake of simplicity.

Here is my terminal output from my tasks.json build task:

```
> Executing task: clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -o main.out main.cpp -I/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/ --debug <

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'main.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

main.cpp is clearly in the folder that I am trying to include with -I (see the following screenshot): [image: clang]

What the heck am I missing here??? I am very tempted to switch my C++ IDE to either Visual Studio or Xcode, as besides this issue, VSCode's C++ autocomplete is buggy and terribly slow.

Note that I am new to using clang++. I have read through 5-10 other SO posts of others going through similar issues, none of which have helped. I also haven't found anything helpful on Clang quickstart guides on LLVM or Microsoft's website.

If anyone needs more info to answer the question, just let me know.

Someone, please help! Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
I figured I would also include my tasks.json, c_cpp_properties.json, and launch.json files.

tasks.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build with Clang",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "clang++",
      "args": [
        "-Wall",
        "-std=c++17",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        "-o",
        "main.out",
        "main.cpp",
        "-I${workspaceFolder}/cpp/main/",
        "--debug"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/boost_1_71_0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "browse": {
                "path": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(lldb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/main.out",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "logging": {
        "trace": true,
        "traceResponse": true,
        "engineLogging": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess clang++ is invoked in `${workspaceFolder}` instead of `${workspaceFolder}/cpp/main`. Could you change the argument `main.cpp` to `${workspaceFolder}/cpp/main/main.cpp` and try again?

Comment: Besides, the `program` field in your `launch.json` has not been configured yet.

Comment: @YangHanlin Your suggestion in changing the `main.cpp` argument worked. Is this the standard method, or am I able to use -I or some other flag to provide directories that should be recursively searched for main.cpp?